# For .Net core webapi and angular, Signalr response not getting client side from server side when SignalR client has connected to server

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8

I have created one web application using .Net core web api as backend side and angular8 as front-side.

Now we implemented signalr feature.

sometimes signalR not working, when SignalR client has connected to the server but gets no message from the server.

I added my signalR backend code as backend side as follows.

await hubContext.Clients.Client(userSignalrCnnectionID).SendAsync("updatescards", cardupdates)

I already checked some property after send signalr for both cases(when signalr working or when signalR not working) like Status(its value "RanToCompletion"), IsCompleted(its value true), IsCompletedSuccessfully(its value true), IsFaulted(its value false), IsCancelled(its value false).

Please let me know why sometimes not getting response message from front-side(i checked not getting any exception from backend code)

Comment: Just sharing one cause because a similar issue has been reported multiple times on this site: before registering any event handler, connection to signal server is started. Your issue could be different, could you share client code ?

Comment: Have you tried to [enable SignalR logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and check if any useful information are collected in logs? And if you send message/data to all connected clients `await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("updatescards", cardupdates)`, does it work well?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your wonderful answer.

I added trace/debug logs in from the side(angular side) as per your suggestion.
[Trace_Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goKh2.jpg)
I noticed every time getting a response from backend API but sometimes message response not getting that time I got 11 lengths. if data is coming then the length is more than 100. Please check my below screenshots.

1. [Not_Getting_Message_Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5fzy.png)
2. [Getting_Message_Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bAHO.png)

Comment: You should focus on response the question. Use the answer section to make additional comments or questions is not the proper use the forum.